# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'bulk_sms_list.pn' when trying to make a column unique

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make a column in a my sql table, that is described below, unique. When I try to execute the command I get `ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'bulk_sms_list.pn'`

The table:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE bulk_sms_list
-> ;
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname   | text | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lname   | text | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pn      | text | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message | text | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| send    | int  | NO   |     | 1       |                |
+---------+------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Below is the sql statement:

```
UPDATE TABLE `bulk_sms_list` ADD UNIQUE(`pn`(255));
```

This table is already populated with values.

Comment: That simply means the column `pn` already have duplicate values. Should it have duplicate values? If no, then do some checking. If yes, then determine at least another column to combine with `pn` and become unique constraint.

Comment: I assume you mean `alter table` rather than `update table`.